# Where to find AGI (Annual Gross Income) on Online Transcript?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, irs

If I may ask for some assistance regarding the Online Transcript: As far as I'm aware of, the Online Transcript (IRS) is separated on four different files: Account Transcript, Record of Account Transcript, Return Transcript, Wage & Income Transcript. I have two questions:

1. Where and in which file do I find AGI? I tried doing "agi" and "annual gross" keywords search in each of the files of Online Transcript but nothing was found. Could anyone please explain to me where exactly in Online Transcript can be AGI found? I did some research on this and find out that if not having w2/paystub then Online Transcript is pretty much the only hope of getting AGI.
2. How do I find out for which year the AGI is? Where is this defined in Online Transcript and in which file?

Appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

AGI actually stands for *Adjusted* (not Annual) Gross Income, so that may be part of your problem.

1. The IRS recommends you use the 'Return Transcript' for AGI. Search for
   `ADJUSTED GROSS INCOME` or `ADJUSTED GROSS INCOME PER COMPUTER` (hopefully they match). For
   me it's about a third of the way down the second page.
2. There is a return transcript for each year. The transcript also says at the top, e.g. `Tax Period Ending: Dec. 31, 2019`.